# query to find closest lesser date

Tags: mysql, sql, case, aggregate-functions

I have a table with lunch effective date and its rate.

I need to display rate from its nearest lesser `effective date (created_on)` for each `date` column.

`lunch_rate` table:

```
created_on |   rate
-----------+-------
2018-06-01 |   30
2018-06-04 |   60
```

Here's what I tried to do:

```
    SELECT userId, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN date= '2018-06-01' AND lunchStatus = 1 THEN (SELECT MAX(rate) FROM lunch_rate WHERE DATE(created_on) <= date LIMIT 1) ELSE 0 END) '2018-06-01',
    SUM(CASE WHEN date= '2018-06-02' AND lunchStatus = 1 THEN (SELECT MAX(rate) FROM lunch_rate WHERE DATE(created_on) <= date LIMIT 1) ELSE 0 END) '2018-06-02',
    SUM(CASE WHEN date= '2018-06-03' AND lunchStatus = 1 THEN (SELECT MAX(rate) FROM lunch_rate WHERE DATE(created_on) <= date LIMIT 1) ELSE 0 END) '2018-06-03',
    SUM(CASE WHEN date= '2018-06-04' AND lunchStatus = 1 THEN (SELECT MAX(rate) FROM lunch_rate WHERE DATE(created_on) <= date LIMIT 1) ELSE 0 END) '2018-06-04'
    FROM
    (        
        SELECT userId, lunchStatus, DATE(issuedDateTime) as date 
        FROM `lunch_status` 
        WHERE DATE(issuedDateTime) BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-06-04'        
    ) as a
    GROUP BY userId;
```

But this query only gives maximum rate of all, without considering the nearest effective date.

Here's the outcome:

```
userId    |   2018-06-01   |   2018-06-02  |  2018-06-03  |  2018-06-04
------------------------------------------------------------------------
131       |   60           |   60          |   0          |  60   
132       |   60           |   60          |  60          |   0
133       |   0            |    0          |   0          |  60
134       |   0            |    0          |   0          |  60
```

Expected outcome:

```
userId    |   2018-06-01   |   2018-06-02  |  2018-06-03  |  2018-06-04
------------------------------------------------------------------------
131       |   30           |   30          |   0          |  60   
132       |   30           |   30          |  30          |   0
133       |   0            |    0          |   0          |  60
134       |   0            |    0          |   0          |  60

SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN (SELECT MAX(rate) FROM lunch_rate WHERE DATE(created_on) <= date LIMIT 1) ELSE 0 END) ....',
```

How can I select lunch rate that was effective on that date?

Comment: Sample data for `lunch_rate` isn't enough , Can you include proper data for these 4 dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the calculation in the subquery:

```
SELECT userId, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2018-06-01' AND lunchStatus = 1
                THEN rate ELSE 0
           END) as `2018-06-01`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2018-06-02' AND lunchStatus = 1
                THEN rate ELSE 0
           END) as `2018-06-02`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2018-06-03' AND lunchStatus = 1
                THEN rate ELSE 0
           END) as `2018-06-03`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN date = '2018-06-04' AND lunchStatus = 1
                THEN rate ELSE 0
           END) as `2018-06-04`
FROM (SELECT ls.*, DATE(ls.issuedDateTime) as date
             (SELECT lr.rate
              FROM lunch_rate lr
              WHERE DATE(lr.created_on) <= DATE(ls.issuedDateTime)
              ORDER BY lr.created_on DESC
              LIMIT 1
             ) as rate
      FROM lunch_status ls
      WHERE DATE(issuedDateTime) BETWEEN '2018-06-01' AND '2018-06-04'        
     ) lr
GROUP BY lr.userId;
```

Note the other changes:

- The subquery for `lunch_rate` does not use `MAX()`.  Instead, it uses `ORDER BY`.
- The column aliases are surrounded by backticks, not single quotes.  I don't approve of the names (because they need to be escaped).  But if you want them, use proper escape characters.
- The tables are given reasonable aliases and column names are qualified.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT lr1.rate
FROM   lunch_rate lr1
WHERE  lr1.created_on <= my_date
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   lunch_rate lr2
                   WHERE  lr2.created_on > lr1.created_on
                     AND  lr2.created_on <= my_date);
```